# Triangle Inequality for this metric

Tags: metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum, triangle-inequality

Let $(X,\varrho)$ be a metric space, and define $d:X\times X\to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$d(x,y)=\inf\lbrace\varrho(x,z)+\varrho(z,y):z\in X\rbrace$$

Show that $d$ is a metric on $X$.

I have all the axioms but the triangle inequality, and just need to find the way to actually leverege that $\varrho$ obeys the triangle inequality in order to finish, but that infimum is stopping me.

Comment: Don't you have to assume that $z \ne a$ and $z \ne b$ in the definition of $\rho$ ? Otherwise there is nothing to prove : $\rho \equiv d$...

Comment: This is how it was given, and while I agree that there is basically nothing to prove, showing that $\varrho\equiv d$ is still something to show.

Answer (score 2):

$$d(a,c)\le\rho(a,b)+\rho(b,c)$$$$\le d(a,b)+d(b,c),$$
where both $\le$ are by definition of $d,$ and the second one ($\rho\le d$) also uses that $\rho$ satisfies the triangular inequality.

Comment: What it seems like you have implicitly said here is that $d\equiv \varrho$, which I agree with, but would have to go prove separately if I were to use it on this work. I would prefer one that just calls on the definition of $d$

Comment: Nonono I never said $d\equiv \varrho.$ I uniquely relied on the definition of $d.$

Comment: How so, I don't understand.

Comment: And now? (I edited)

Comment: Can you please explain the downvote, to help me to improve again my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (and generating an insight that may not be obvious) is to show that $d(x,y) = \rho (x,y)$ holds.

We have

$$d(x,y) = \inf\,\{\rho(x,z)+\rho(z,y): z \in X\} \le \rho(x,y)+\rho(y,y) = \rho(x,y), \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

by simply choosing $z=y$ and using that $\rho(y,y)=0$.

On the other hand, due to triangualr inequality, we have

$$\forall z \in X: \rho(x,z)+\rho(y,z) \ge \rho(x,y). \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

So $\rho(x,y)$ is a lower bound of the set $\{\rho(x,z)+\rho(z,y): z \in X\}$. With the infimum of a set being the largest lower bound, we get

$$d(x,y) = \inf\,\{\rho(x,z)+\rho(z,y): z \in X\} \ge \rho(x,y).$$

Now \eqref{eq1} and \eqref{eq2} together show $d(x,y) = \rho (x,y).$